# If $A$ and $B$ are sets of real positive numbers, bounded and $C:=\{x\cdot y | x \in A, y \in B\}$ show that $sup(A) sup(B)= sup(C)$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I already know that there are some answers to this problem, but in my case I want to solve a particular question, related to my show process.

Let $A$, $B$ sets of real positive numbers, bounded above. Let $a=sup(A)$, $b=sup(B)$, and $C:=\{x\cdot y | x\in A, y\in B\}$, show that $a\cdot b = sup(C)$.

For any $x \in A$ y $y \in B$, by supreme definition:
$$0 \le x \le a \quad \forall x \in A$$
$$0 \le y \le b \quad \forall y \in B$$
As $x,y,a$ y $b$ are positive reals, it is true that:
$$x\cdot y \le a\cdot b$$
Note that $x\cdot y \in C$, so $a\cdot b$ is an upper bound of $C$, thus being $C \neq \emptyset$ and bounded above, the supreme of $C$ exists (Completeness Axiom). Now we need to show that $a\cdot b$ is the minumum upper bound of $C$. So $a\cdot b = sup(C)$ and $a\cdot b \in C$, then $sup(C)\le a\cdot b$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$, thus by the approximation property of Suprema, we know that exists $x_0 \in A$ y $y_0 \in B$ such that:
$$a - \epsilon < x_0 \le a$$
$$b - \epsilon < y_0 \le b$$
Multipliying the inequalities, we get:
$$(a - \epsilon)(b - \epsilon) < x_0 y_0 \le ab$$

And this is the problem I have, because $\epsilon$ can be greater than $a$ or $b$, and it implies that $a - \epsilon<0$ or $b - \epsilon<0$. But I need to get and expresion like:
$$ab - \epsilon \le x_{0} y_{0} \le sup(C)$$
In order to show that $a\cdot b = sup(C)$.

I thank everyone who can help me.

Comment: Yes, but you're interested in *small* $\epsilon$. If you chose $\epsilon < \frac{a+b}{2}$, then $(a-\epsilon)(b-\epsilon) \geq ab-\frac{a+b}{2}\epsilon$. So you know that for any $\frac{a+b}{2} > \epsilon > 0$, $\sup\,{C} \geq ab-\frac{a+b}{2}\epsilon$, which implies $\frac{2}{a+b}(ab-\sup\,{C}) \leq \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, which forces $ab \leq \sup\,{C}$.